# Equation number is not on the same line because not enough space?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, numbering

How can I format this equation better so that the equation number isn't forced onto the next line like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c  & 3b\\
a^2(j+n)(k+m) & 2b^2(j+k)(n+m) & c^2 + 2(j+k+n)\\
(b+c)^2 +1 & (c+d)^2  & (a+b)^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_A\\
x_B\\
x_C
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
C (d+b)^2 +d^2 \\
1 + a \\
B (c+b)^2 +d^2
\end{bmatrix},
\label{myeqn}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can make a group with a smaller font size:

Comment: And why do you bother doing this? Any attempt to achieve this would just make the equation more ugly!

Comment: I see no other way than to use `multline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a group with a smaller font size:

```
 {\small\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}}
```

or use the  `medsize` environment (~80% of `\displaystyle`), from `nccmath`:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{medsize}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c  & 3b\\
a^2(j+n)(k+m) & 2b^2(j+k)(n+m) & c^2 + 2(j+k+n)\\
(b+c)^2 +1 & (c+d)^2  & (a+b)^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_A\\
x_B\\
x_C
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
C (d+b)^2 +d^2 \\
1 + a \\
B (c+b)^2 +d^2
\end{bmatrix},
\end{medsize}
\label{myeqn}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest decreasing the `\thickmuskip` and `\medmuskip` lengths by a small margin, so 30%, and also using a manual `\mleft`-`\mright` delimiter sizing (it uses less space):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

% Original equation/spacing
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
         a        &       c        &      3b        \\
    a^2(j+n)(k+m) & 2b^2(j+k)(n+m) & c^2 + 2(j+k+n) \\
      (b+c)^2 +1  &    (c+d)^2     &     (a+b)^2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_A \\
    x_B \\
    x_C
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    C (d+b)^2 + d^2 \\
         1 + a      \\
    B (c+b)^2 + d^2
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

% Updated equation with reduced spacing
\begin{equation}
  \setlength{\thickmuskip}{.7\thickmuskip}
  \setlength{\medmuskip}{.7\medmuskip}
  \mleft[\begin{array}{ @{} *{3}{c} @{} }
         a        &       c        &      3b        \\
    a^2(j+n)(k+m) & 2b^2(j+k)(n+m) & c^2 + 2(j+k+n) \\
      (b+c)^2 +1  &    (c+d)^2     &     (a+b)^2
  \end{array}\mright]
  \mleft[\begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
    x_A \\
    x_B \\
    x_C
  \end{array}\mright]
  =
  \mleft[\begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
    C (d+b)^2 + d^2 \\
         1 + a      \\
    B (c+b)^2 + d^2
  \end{array}\mright],
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @egreg, you can use `multline`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c  & 3b\\
    a^2(j+n)(k+m) & 2b^2(j+k)(n+m) & c^2 + 2(j+k+n)\\
    (b+c)^2 +1 & (c+d)^2  & (a+b)^2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_A\\
    x_B\\
    x_C
  \end{bmatrix}
  =\\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    C (d+b)^2 +d^2 \\
    1 + a \\
    B (c+b)^2 +d^2
  \end{bmatrix},
  \label{myeqn}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]